# imap_headerinfo not working

Tags: php, imap

I've been trying to get this to work for about a week. I simply want to retrieve the from, subject and date. I've looked online but all the examples show looping rather than a single email.

I've stripped my code down to the minimum to show you how rubbish I am. Please can anyone help, and I'm sure other newbie's must be having the same issue.

This returns NOTHING, by why? I can't work it out. Must be something simple as I can get the overview page (which loops through all the message in the inbox) to work just fine.

How annoying.

```
$host       = 'mydomain.com';       
$login      = 'username';
$password       = 'password';
$connect        = '{mydomain.com:143/novalidate-cert}#';

$server         = str_replace('localhost', $host, $connect);
$server         = str_replace('#', $folder_start, $server);
$connection = imap_open($server, $login, $password) or senderror("ERROR 1: can't connect: " . imap_last_error(),$email_errors);

$uid            = $_GET['id'];

$header         = imap_headerinfo($connection, $uid);
$body           = imap_body($connection, $uid, FT_UID);


<table>
     <tr>
          <td>From:</td>
          <td><?php echo $header->from; ?></td>
     </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the `imap_body()` call works? Is `$connection` a valid resource?

Comment: Your $connect looks a little strange.  It's connecting to the non-SSL port (is this even open on your server?), but telling to not to validate a certificate?

Comment: Yes this is working fine, I'm using the same $connection on my other page which is looping and pulling all the from, subject & date. So it can't be that?

Answer (score 0):

headerinfo is used incorrectly, instead of uid it uses msgno.

Ref:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php